# How to install Linaro toolchain in windows?

Tags: toolchain, linaro

I find Linaro toolchain in https://www.linaro.org/downloads/

but the files (such as gcc-linaro-6.2.1-2016.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
)  format tar.xz contains symbolic links.

**How can .tar.xz be extracted in windows ?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run the following from your mingw environment:

```
tar xf gcc-linaro-6.2.1-2016.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
```